# how to make scrolling scroll 100% of ViewHight each the user scroll

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I have a wordpress website.
i like to make that site kind of similar to Reels / Tiktok.
when we scroll, instead of scroll step be slowly, each time the user interact with scrolling
it will scroll a whole Section or 100% of the view Hight. both ways will work fine.

what ever method works for me :)

edit: an idea i had, make the smoothweel scroll steps for anchors. then set anchors through the page. each scroll will scroll to the next anchor.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't waste much time with this. Make sure your other elements are as intended and just use something like this:

https://webdevtrick.com/demos/full-page-scrolling/